# 'DropDownList' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items

Tags: c#, asp.net, testing, nunit

I'm currently testing the functionality of a drop down list for a web app. I'm new to testing so I'm not quite sure how to avoid getting this error. After doing some research, I know I have to include a try catch block in order to handle the exception. So far, when I run my test, I am able to test the first option of in the drop down list. Ultimately, I am trying to test each option in the drop down list considering that each option directs the user to a different page. Here is my code:

```
public void GoToProductSelection(string choice)
{
    this.GoToFacilitySelection();
    IWebElement productsDdl = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlProducts")));
    SelectElement options = new SelectElement(productsDdl);
    options.SelectByText(choice);
    IWebElement product = options.SelectedOption;
    IWebElement contBtn;
    IWebElement selCheckBox; 

    string val = (product.GetAttribute("value"));

    IWebElement addToOrderBtn = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAddItem"));
    addToOrderBtn.Click();

    try
    {

    }
    catch (NoAlertPresentException)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to wrap the `try {...}` portion of the try-catch block around the code where you want to catch any thrown exceptions. Your code as it stands won't catch anything because the `try` section is empty.

Comment: I wasn't sure what to include in the try-catch block so I just left it empty. Would this be the code I would need to include in the try section?                          try
            {
                SelectElement options = new SelectElement(productsDdl);
                options.SelectByText(choice);
                IWebElement product = options.SelectedOption;
               
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm uncertain as to whether your question is in regards to the try/catch, testing in general or the actual error thrown (invalid Selected value).

Your try/catch should be structured as follows.

```
public void GoToProductSelection(string choice)
{
    try
    {
        this.GoToFacilitySelection();
        IWebElement productsDdl = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlProducts")));
        SelectElement options = new SelectElement(productsDdl);
        options.SelectByText(choice);
        IWebElement product = options.SelectedOption;
        IWebElement contBtn;
        IWebElement selCheckBox; 

        string val = (product.GetAttribute("value"));

        IWebElement addToOrderBtn = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAddItem"));
        addToOrderBtn.Click();
    }
    catch (NoAlertPresentException)
    {
        //code to handle NoAlertPresentException
    }
}
```

When an exception is thrown within a try block the CLR looks for the catch statement that handles this exception. If nothing is in the try block then no exception will ever be thrown within the block and the catch will never be hit.